# Why is my field not in $_POST when it is in the HTTP Form Data?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have an HTML form with `method="POST"`.  There is a button with `name="submit"` in the form, plus a large number of hidden input fields with various names and values.  I can see all the expected data coming through in the Request Header Form Data in my browser inspector.  However, the `submit` field is not present in `$_POST` in the php script that is the form's `action` target.

What am I doing wrong?

Some extra tidbits:

- Changing the name of the button doesn't help.  The new name is still in the Form Data but not in `$_POST`
- When I comment out all the hidden fields, it works fine
- The HTML passes validation
- The button has a non-empty value

Comment: I can think of several possibilities; try providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed up bump up the `max_input_vars` value in my `php.ini` file.  The number of hidden inputs was greater than `max_input_vars` and so `$_POST` was getting truncated, leaving off my `submit` input var.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  Thanks for the heads-up.  I found the answer just after posting the question.

Comment: are you really replying to yourself in an answer to you own question?

Comment: Haha, I had replied to someone else pointing out to me that there's a checkbox in the Ask a Question form for if I plan to answer my own question, but I guess they deleted their comment.